# Do I need Norton Internet Security if my Windows 8 machine has Windows Defender?

Tags: windows-8, windows-defender, norton-internet-security

I got a new Windows 8 laptop. It comes with Norton Internet Security pre-installed. Do I need this if Windows 8 comes with Windows Defender?

Can I safely uninstall Norton Internet Security?

Comment: Windows Defender is the same type of software as Norton Anti-Virus. You will have to make the decision to remove it or purchase the subscription to Norton. Only your opinion of Norton is important.  Of course you can remove Norton Internet Security its just software.

Comment: I personally would say that you don't need either. It's just like having sex in real life. If you just watch where you put that thing, it won't get sick. IOW try to stay on the main roads of the net, use an effective adblock and don't dl random exe's, then you won't get viruses. I know people that get them all the time because they think they need the program that "manages all your forum accounts with one easy login". Meanwhile I've not had a virus in 20yr and don't run an antivirus. I'm just mindful of 'where I put it'.

Comment: @Monsto, You hadn't any virus in 20yrs? Ok just install Trial version of kaspersky or Bitdefender and scan your computer, Then check the result... Many website has Malicious code even famous websites... Maybe you are just playing with wine in windows..!

Comment: @SepahradSalour Matter of fact, I had just this conversation last w'end with a coworker of the wife (she's a ms/cisco admin at work) and he said much the same. I use comodo firewall and for the sake of consistency ran their free AV. Aside from a handful of expected false positives (which I won't go into) it found nothing except an IE add-on that it didn't like. Bottom line is that I don't use shifty websites or click odd ads or install things that I don't  know where they've been. An AV is there to pay attention when the user either can't or doesn't know how to. I just pay attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your Norton Internet Security, is on a free trial basis only. If you are unwilling to pay once the free trial is over, free and effective alternatives are available to Norton (and Windows Defender - if desired, previously known as Microsoft Security Essentials in Windows 7)

- conduct a google search for **free antivirus**.

Uninstallation of NIS from your Windows 8 PC can be seen from the official documentation [here](https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/solutions/v24120365_NIS_Retail_2013_en_us)

Comment: I disagree about Windows Defender it has detect every signature I have thrown at it.  I have personal experience with AVG which has corrupted installations of operating systems email stored by Thunderbird ( actually corrupted the messages so they were incomplete ).

Comment: @Ramhound, I'm sorry you have had a bad experience with AVG. I'm happy to hear you have had a good experience with Windows Defender however.

Comment: @Ramhound See this article http://m.techspot.com/news/50945-microsoft-security-essentials-bombs-tests-loses-av-test-certificate.html

Comment: For John Q. Public License, AVG is fine. I have found it to be way too liberal with false positives, but I don't believe the comment is -1 worthy.

Comment: @monsto I guess everyone's experience is different. The general consensus on Windows Defender in Win 8 is not good, but that doesn't mean to say it is that way for everyone.

Comment: @SepahradSalour Much appreciated, the facts laid bare.

Comment: You linked to a year old article that's a lifetime in the security industry the article is pure opinion

Comment: @Ramhound Just in the same respect that your experience of Windows Defender with Windows 8 is your opinion. I'm not dissing Windows Defender I hope it is or does become a leading AV solution, but there are better free AV available such as Avast.

Comment: @Simon - This is the reason I don't believe you should have suggested any product.  The only question that should have been answered is can Norton be removed safetly.  You only highly the poor performance of Windows Defender and none of the problems that exists with AVG and Avast or Avira or any of the other options you didn't list.

Comment: @Ramhound If you wish I can edit my answer to remove reference to AVG, Avast, Avira and Windows Defender.

Comment: @Ramhound Have now re edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I have just Windows Defender on my Windows 8 operating system. I think that it is actually a very good antivirus software. The thing is that different antivirus software use different methods to protect you against malware. Before i was using Avira Antivirus on Windows 7 and it was very good, but then I tried Microsoft Security Essentials and was very satisfied. That is the reason i am sticking with Windows Defender on Windows 8. So i would suggest you to uninstall Norton Internet Security and just use Windows Defender. Download also Malwarebytes the free version and from time to time do a full system scan.

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall Norton internet security using the Norton removal tool provided my Norton you can down load the same from the link

https://support.norton.com/sp/en/in/home/current/solutions/kb20080828154508EN_EndUserProfile_en_us